# Catch exception when connection to database Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, exception, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to check every time my application runs that I am connected to the database, if not I want to generate an alert. I am using Spring Boot with Spring Data JPA and I have my database details configured in my application.properties. My question is, where does database connection happen in Spring Data JPA, and can I catch exception so I can perform some logic?

Comment: Since Connecting to database happens through Autoconfiguration in spring boot, I dont believe you can catch the exception and do a fallback logic. Having said that, you can configure springboot to continue with the startup even if database connection fails.

Comment: I am not a friend of custom code but as a database  connection is often a required dependency the absense of a database should be a dealbreaker and not a alert (except influxdb for statistical data). To implement a cuatom datasource might help.

Answer (score 1):

You can getConnection from DataSource.
If is connection is not ok, then getConnection will throw a exception.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "packages")
public class MyApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext = SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class);

        DataSource dataSource = springContext.getBean(DataSource.class);
        try {
            // if connection is not ok, then getConnection throw exception
            dataSource.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // try connection error here
        }
    }
}
```